# AWS + RDS result backend celery

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-rds

How can I write a valid URL to use celery results from the backend with AWS RDS.
I would like to use AWS RDS as my results backend.

I'm using two EC2 instances, one running Django and the other remote with celery, I would like to save the results of the tasks in an RDS instance.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To use Celery with AWS RDS as backend, you can use the [SQLAlchemy backend for Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/sqlalchemy.html).

The url will depend on which dbms is being used, user, pass, host, port and db name. For AWS RDS Postgres, the RESULT_BACKEND could be something like: `sqla+postgresql://user:pass@xxxxxxx.yyyyyy.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname`

**Warning**: There is a caveat on [Celery documentation about using SQLAlchemy](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html): "... Historically, SQLAlchemy has not been the most stable result backend so if chosen one should proceed with caution"

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the official documentation of Celery, they do not provide any information on how to use RDS as a database.

[How to configure different backends for Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#conf-result-backend)

Since it requires an additional dependency([S3 backend driver](https://pypi.org/project/s3/)) to connect to S3 to use it as a DB, you can use [Boto3](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/) and can follow the same procedure as mentioned for S3.

Personally, I haven't tried it so, it can be a hit or miss.

Comment: RDS runs a database server of your choice (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc..) You don't use boto3 to connect to an RDS database, you use a standard database driver for the database engine you chose. Celery doesn't provide info on connecting to RDS because there is nothing specific about RDS that would need to be explained, you just use the same technique you would use to connect Celery to a MySQL or PostgreSQL database running anywhere.